# Need to add qty of two different dates as partial dates in a week which is in different month but it should be display as first day of the week

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to add qty of two different dates as partial dates in a week which is in different month but it should be display as first day of the week

| Item | subm | loc | startdate | Type | Fcst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | 26-02-2023 | 6 | 36.10988944 |
| a | b | c | 01-03-2023 | 6 | 48.14651925 |
| a | b | c | 05-03-2023 | 6 | 60.09763211 |
| a | b | c | 12-03-2023 | 6 | 23.84474793 |

I need data like this :-

| Item | subm | loc | startdate | Type | Fcst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | 26-02-2023 | 6 | 84.25640869 |
| a | b | c | 05-03-2023 | 6 | 60.09763211 |
| a | b | c | 12-03-2023 | 6 | 23.84474793 |

which is addition of both and need to store in xy table

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, e.g. where rows are not merged. (Don't forget to adjust the expected result.)

Comment: Item    subm    loc startdate   Type    Fcst

a b c 26-02-2023 6 36.10988944
a b c 01-03-2023 6 48.14651925
a b c 05-03-2023 6 60.09763211
a b c 12-03-2023 6 23.84474793


Expected result 

Item    subm    loc startdate   Type    Fcst

a  b c 26-02-2023 6 84.25640869
a b c 05-03-2023 6 60.09763211
a b c 12-03-2023 6 23.84474793

Comment: So, you consider Sunday the first day of the week. And you want one result row per item, subm, locweek, and week. Yes?

Comment: Correct need sunday as a first day of the week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ISO week. An ISO week starts with the Monday, so just add a day, get the ISO week start day and then subtract the day again.

```
select
  item,
  subm,
  loc,
  trunc(startdate + 1, 'iw') - 1 as sunday,
  type,
  sum(fcst) as fcst_sum
from mytable
group by item, subm, loc, trunc(startdate + 1, 'iw') - 1, type
order by item, subm, loc, trunc(startdate + 1, 'iw') - 1, type;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/5EmzRiW7